# Proper way of extend /opt with lvm and xfs filesystem

Tags: lvm, xfs

I am keen to know more about the proper way to extend /opt after additional hard disk 5GB with lvm and xfs filesystem. Kindly advised. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

- grow logical volume (if you have space)
- grow filesystem

**Details**:

I can't grow an `/opt` FS, I will use `/opt2`

my initial size  is 5G

```
linux# df -h /opt2
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgdata-opt2  5.0G   33M  5.0G   1% /opt2
```

I check for space in `vgdata`

```
linux# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg00     1   9   0 wz--n- <44.51g <10.02g
  vgdata   1   2   0 wz--n- <16.00g  <8.00g
```

fine, I have 8G available in `vgdata`. I use `lvresize` command to grow logical volume `/dev/mapper/vgdata-opt2`

```
linux# lvresize --size=+5G /dev/mapper/vgdata-opt2
  Size of logical volume vgdata/opt2 changed from 5.00 GiB (1280 extents) to 10.00 GiB (2560 extents).
  Logical volume vgdata/opt2 successfully resized.
```

however, space is not allocated in FS

```
linux# df -h /opt2
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgdata-opt2  5.0G   33M  5.0G   1% /opt2
```

I expand filesystem, for `xfs` filesystem, comamnd is `xfs_growfs /mountpoint` , resizing can be done with FS mounted.

```
linux# xfs_growfs /opt2
meta-data=/dev/mapper/vgdata-opt2 isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=327680 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=1310720, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 1310720 to 2621440
```

let's check space.

```
linux# df -h /opt2
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgdata-opt2   10G   33M   10G   1% /opt2
linux#
```

Comment: If your distribution includes the `fsadm` tool and a modern enough version of the LVM tools, you can have `lvresize` handle the filesystem extension automatically: `lvresize --resizefs --size=+5G /dev/mapper/vgdata-opt2` and then it will run `xfs_growfs` automatically for you.